# Office 365 - Request for notifications after certain datetime - webhooks using Graph api

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

After subscribing for notifications (Created, Updated,Deleted), if for whatever reasons our daemon/service that receives notifications goes down, what are the ways to receive notifications again? Can we query for updates/notifications based on an ID OR a datetime?

Comment: Please refer the below mentioned blog for "Subscribe webhooks to get change notifications"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-sync

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot query for notifications. However, Graph Webhook will try to resend the notifications a number of times **within ~4 hours** window. If your service backs up again within that time frame, then you will receive the notifications that cannot be delivered to you during your service down time.

Comment: So, when the service is back online after a shutdown AND there are few pending notifications that are supposed to be sent out, should the service send any additional parameters in order to receive those pending ones? I haven't seen this scenario working and hence the question.

Comment: The service does not need to send anything. Graph webhook has its own schedule on resending the notifications, so you might not receive the pending ones right after your service gets backed up. Have you waited for sometimes to see the expected notifications delivered to you eventually?

Comment: Thanks for your updates @Cuong Pham.
Looks like I didn't get any of the pending notifications, but started receiving notifications for the newer ones. Are you saying pending notifications can be sent out at a random time (within 4 hrs. timeline)?